# Tag synonym request: pillow → python-imaging-library

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

[python-imaging-library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-imaging-library) has 3,380 questions and [pillow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pillow) has 973 questions.

[Pillow](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow) is a maintained fork of [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_Imaging_Library says:

> Development [of PIL] appears to be discontinued with the last commit to the PIL repository coming in 2011. Consequently, a successor project called Pillow has forked the PIL repository and added Python 3.x support. This fork has been adopted as a replacement for the original PIL in Linux distributions including Debian and Ubuntu (since 13.04).

I suggest that in 2017 there's no need to differentiate between the two, and that [pillow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pillow) can be set as a synonym for [python-imaging-library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-imaging-library); that is, only the [python-imaging-library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-imaging-library) tag will be used, and if you use [pillow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pillow) it'll just redirect to [python-imaging-library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-imaging-library).

(There's already [pil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pil) and [python-pil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-pil) remapping onto [python-imaging-library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-imaging-library).)

Comment: So what about people who still use the (original) PIL aka Python Imaging Library and not Pillow? I don't think you can merge two tags like that. It would create a lot of confusion since that PIL and Pillow are actually two different things. Yes, Pillow is a fork of PIL, but it's not *the same* as PIL. Python-PIL  and PIL mapping to Python-Imaging-Library makes sense since they only are acronyms, but in this case is different.

Comment: People who still use the original PIL still have a tag with the same name: [tag:python-imaging-library]. They're also using code with security [vulnerabilities](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvekey.cgi?keyword=pil).

Comment: Yeah, and people who use Pillow will be mistaken for people using the old PIL. Doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: In any case, it'd still be important to say which version of PIL or Pillow they are using.

Comment: Well that's a rule of thumb for any library with more than one version.

Comment: I know absolutely nothing about these libraries, but if Pillow is the current and maintained library, shouldn't *it* be the primary tag?

Comment: PIL (all upper case, an acronym for Python Imaging Library) is recognizable to everyone that uses PIL or Pillow. If there were to be a common tag, I would suggest PIL would be the natural choice. It's also the name that Pillow installs itself under, and it's the name Christian Lund gave the library.  Pillow is more like a new version than anything else.

Comment: Approved by community vote and therefore [status-completed] (note that I personally don't quite agree with the synonym).